# How do I Work Around " Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: ""\x9D"" from Windows-1252 to UTF-8"?

Tags: ruby

Here's the code that generates the error:

```
issues.each 
{ 
    |issue| 
    response = RestClient::Request.new
    (
        :method => :get,
        :url => "http://wls-eng1:8080/rest/api/2/issue/{issue['key']}/comment", 
        :user => username,
        :password => password,
        :headers => { :accept => :json, :content_type => :json },
        :ssl_ca_file => :temp
    ).execute
}
```

Comment: In url string should be `#{issue['key']}` instead of just `{issue['key']}`

Comment: Thanks actually I did have it that way. Guess I didn't cut n paste it correctly. Looking for some way to ignore the invalid character.

Comment: Well, try to escape chars, there is a variant: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html